# Calculating area using double integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area, multiple-integral

I'm homelearning double integrals and currently trying to learn how to calculate the area using double integrals.

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> We have a area bounded by 4 curves: $y=\frac{1}{x}, y^2=x, y=2, x=0$.
>   Calculate it's area.

Could you please help me determine which integrals to calculate? I know how to do it with single variable  integrals, but I'm not sure how to define the integrals in multivariable calculus.

Thanks

Comment: you have $0\le x\le\frac{1}{y}$ and $\sqrt{x}\le y\le 2$

Comment: @HenryLee That's the boundaries, but how do I get the functions to integrate?

Comment: Is you able to draw  graph with given curves ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area that you are interested in is the area bounded by the $4$ thick lines from the next picture:

[image]

There are points $(x,y)$ in that region with $y$ taking any value from $0$ to $2$. For every such $y$, the values that $x$ can take go from $0$ to:

- $\sqrt x$ if $x\in[0,1]$;
- $\frac1x$ if $x\in[1,2]$.

So, compute$$\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt x}1\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy+\int_1^2\int_0^{1/x}1\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy.$$

Comment: Thanks, so I use $1$ as function and use my curves as boundaries.

Comment: I have no idea about what it is to “use $1$ as function”.

Comment: I used it as a number.

Answer (score 0):

The integrand is 1 in double integral. The area is calculated by summing up all the small areas $\mathrm dS = \mathrm dx \mathrm dy$.

To proceed, we cut the bounded area into two parts, and there are two common plans to do this.

**Plan A**:
Cut the area with $x=1/2$ ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceKOH.png)).
$$
\int^{1/2}_0 \mathrm dx \int_{\sqrt x}^2 \mathrm dy
+
\int^{1}_{1/2} \mathrm dx \int_{\sqrt x}^{1/x} \mathrm dy.
$$

**Plan B**:
Cut the area with $y=1$ ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TA0b.png)).
$$
\int^{1}_0 \mathrm dy \int_{0}^{y^2} \mathrm dx
+
\int^{2}_1 \mathrm dy \int_{0}^{1/y} \mathrm dx.
$$

Both give you the answer $\color{Green}{\ln 2 + 1/3}$.